# From M2Crypto to pyCrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto, pypy, m2crypto

I'm trying to port an M2Crypto function to pyCrypto or any other solution, 'cause the last version of M2Crypto doesn't work with pypy.

So, i'm trying to port an existing code from pysimplesoap:
https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap/blob/master/pysimplesoap/xmlsec.py

This is the only function that i don't know how to port:

```
def x509_extract_rsa_public_key(cert, binary=False):
    "Return the public key (PEM format) from a X509 certificate"
    x509 = x509_parse_cert(cert, binary)
    return x509.get_pubkey().get_rsa().as_pem()
```

The original public certificate is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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```

And when i execute that function, the result is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I was trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
pub = open("certificate_server.crt", "r").read()
a2 = crypto.load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, pub)
b2 = a2.get_pubkey()
```

But then i don't know how to proceed, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, this is a M2Crypto maintainer. Just curious: when was the last time when ``pypy`` worked with M2Crypto?

Answer (score 0):

Using pyOpenSSL, after you call `get_pubkey()` you can call `OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, b2)` to get the PEM output.